# Cannot 'Load data local infile' while source CSV file is opened in Excel

Tags: mysql, excel, vb.net, winforms

This issue is rather old for me, but so far it was bearable. But now I need to get rid of it. I am delevoping Winforms app, which among others has the function to import CSV files to MySQL database on another server.

As far as the source CSV file is not opened in Excel there are absolutely no issues with importing. Also if file is opened in Notepad or Notepad++ all is fine. But if file is opened in Excel it cannot be imported in database. When showing processlist in MySQL client you can see the state as "Receiving from client" for a minute or two and then VisualStudio ends execution with exception 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' (the complete exception message is shown below). Just for comparison if I import this CSV file using HeidiSQL there are no issues when file is opened in Excel.

The code for loading is below:

```
importStr = "Load data local infile '" + selectedPath.Replace("\", "\\") + fileName + 
"' into table " + targetTable + columns terminated by '" + TextBox1.Text + "'
optionally enclosed by '""' lines terminated by '" + TextBox2.Text + "' ignore 1 lines"
```

This results in following command:

```
Load data local infile 'E:\\New\\def_charts_cell_3ser.csv'
    into table def_charts_cell_3ser_temp
    columns terminated by ','
    optionally enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\r\n'
    ignore 1 lines
```

Importing string is used as follows:

```
Queries.ExecQueryAdminNoSess(importStr, MysqlConn)
```

The definition of sub is below:

```
    Public Shared Sub ExecQueryAdminNoSess(queryString As String, MysqlConn As MySqlConnection)
        Dim SQL As New MySqlCommand

        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()

            SQL.Connection = MysqlConn
            SQL.CommandText = queryString
            SQL.CommandTimeout = 1200

            SQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch Err As MySqlException
            MsgBox("Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Close()
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Full text of exception:

*Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock'
Message=Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' : 'The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0xf35008 to COM context 0xf34f50 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.'*

Comment: This method scares me, as it will force you to write code that will be crazy-vulnerable to sql injection issues. It's also re-using the same connection object through the app, which is not good practice and will actually make your app slower and create bottlenecks. It really is better to create a band new connection object for most queries.

Comment: In fact I am using new connections for almost all queries. But this query is a part of a bunch of queries, which manipulate the same temporary MySQL tables, which are supposed to exist within the same session.

Comment: How about temporarily copying the csv to another location to guarantee that it won't be locked by Excel?

Comment: Exactly what I did :) I will post this work-around as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The work-around that I implemented and solved my question is to copy the CSV file in the same folder, but with different name. After that this new file is loaded in MySQL database and finally this new file is deleted. Below is the code.

```
If File.Exists(selectedPath + fileNameOrig) Then
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(selectedPath + fileNameOrig, selectedPath + fileNameCopy),
                                    FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
    
    *do file contents injection in database*
    
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(selectedPath + fileNameCopy)
End If
```